# What does the const keyword do in an operator definition?

Tags: c++, operators

I don't understand what the const keyword is used for in front of the return type and after the parameter list of this operator definition. This is taken from an example from a book.

```
const char& operator [] (int num) const
{
    if (num < getlength())
        return Buffer[num];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ `const` keyword basically means "something cannot change, or cannot delegate operations that change onto other entities." This refers to a specific variable: either an arbitrary variable declaration, or implicitly to `this` in a member function.

The `const` *before* the function name is part of the return type:

```
const char&
```

This is a reference to a `const char`, meaning it is not possible to assign a new value to it:

```
foo[2] = 'q'; // error
```

The `const` at the end of the function definition means "this function cannot change `this` object and cannot call non-const functions on *any* object." In other words, invoking this function cannot change *any* state.

```
const char& operator [] (int num) const {
  this->modifySomething(); // error
  Buffer.modifySomething(); // error
  return Buffer[num];
}
```

The goal of `const`-correctness is a big topic, but the short version is being able to guarantee that immutable state actually is immutable. This helps with thread safety and helps the compiler optimize your code.

Comment: > and cannot call non-const functions on any object."  you probably mean of any member variable. It actually can call nonconst method of nonconst parameters/local/global vars

Answer (score 0):

It means the actual object you are calling this method on will not change, and if you attempt to change it, you'll get a compiler error.